How to read data from Philips P2000C over its serial port to a modern computer?
I would like to interface with my Philips P2000C computer over its serial port (V24) using a serial-to-USB cable. Notably, my P2000C has a 8088 CoPower expansion board and I am working in an MS-DOS environment.
To understand the communication protocol, I initially hooked up PIN2 (TxD) of the serial port to my oscilloscope and wrote a small 8088-assembly program in MS-DOS debug to send over some bytes.
mov ah,1
mov al,55
int 14
mov ah,1
mov al,aa
int 14
mov ah,1
mov al,55
int 14
int 20

The readout of the oscilloscope can be found below.

If I understand this readout correctly, the communication protocol has the following characteristics:

BAUD rate: 1200
Bytesize: 8
One stop bit
No parity
No flow control

When I however hook up the serial port via a USB to serial cable (see images below) to a modern computer and try to receive the bytes, I get nothing.


I am using PuTTy. The cable that I use is recognized in Windows as having a CH340g chip. I use the COM port as specified in the device manager.

Am I using the right cable?
Am I using the right protocol?
Are these serial-to-USB adapters compatible with voltage ranges used in RS232?
Any suggestions how to bottleneck this?


he Question misses a lot of important information. Isn't the P2000C a Z80 CP/M machine? So I assume you're using the 8088 co-processor? Have you checked the pinout ?  Are you using a null-modem cable/plug? And so on...

It should work, but you did not say in which way you connected those two ports together. Which pin to which? How long cable? Are you sure BIOS does not use handshaking?

@IvoFilot That gray adapter between two hosts (old and new PC) must be a null modem adapter. If it isn't, it won't work, and if you or we don't know which adapter it is the it can be the issue. Even if RS-232 standard is 60 years old, it's very much used today.

Makes me wish I didn't retire my old Philips oscilloscope collection, but they were all broken. Should have debugged this problem with a matching scope.

Most likely you need what's called a null-modem cable with two female 9-pin connectors, that connects pin 5 of one connector (call it X) to pin 5 of the other connector (Y), pin 2 of X to pin 3 of Y, and pin 3 of X to pin 2 of Y.  If you're using just those three wires, set handshake to "none".  Adding more wires to the cable would allow use of handshaking, which might increase the rate at data may be transfered reliably, but for purposes of getting something to happen, using the above three wires with handshaking off would be a good place to start.

Thanks for your answer! I was under the impression that the cable am using would be such a null-modem cable. Nevertheless, I have now ordered a fresh one as well a 'professional' RS232 to USB adapter. For now, I'll accept this answer as it points me in the right direction to proceed. Once I received the new cable and adapter and got things to work, I'll write a separate answer explaining upon the details.

@IvoFilot The "cable" is USB. The whole "RS232 USB adapter" is a DTE just like the old PC is a DTE. You need a "null-modem cable" or "null-modem adapter plug" between two PCs, regardless of their age.

@IvoFilot Usually not, Serial cabling/pinout is designed to connect computers to peripherals (Printer, Modem, etc.) as simple 1:1 connection as that's the standard use case. Connecting two computers is a non standard usage and requires a null-modem. USB converter cables are for the standard use case, so you can connect a serial printer to your modern PC. To use it to another computer a null-modem is always needed (or resoldering the wires :)). Note, there are also dedicated USB to other computer cables available (usually notable more expensive).

I've dug out the reason why it does not work. The Philips computer uses incorrect connector which allows you to connect to it with adapters that are not intended to be connected between two computers.

@IvoFilot As you apparently have an oscilloscope, you can measure which pin of the RS232 end of the serial USB part sends in the same manner. Use PuTTY to send a stream of characters, put something on the keyboard so that for example the space bar is pressed. Now you have the pin numbers and you can check the wiring.

@thebusybee There is no reason to verify the USB adapter - these can be assumed standard like all of them. However the manual of Philips P2000C says it uses DTE pinout while it clearly uses DCE connector so no need to measure with scope, it will just prove what is already known and why the setup in the question does not work.

@Justme We see that the wiring is the problem. So this is just a hint how to solve such problems. I did not say to verify the adapter, just how to find which pins are sending.

@supercat Thank you once more for your answer. Very much appreciated. It pointed me in the right direction and I got everything to work. As promised, I have written a brief summary on the details as a separate answer.

The problem is that the Philips computer has a non-standard connector gender. The computer is wired as a 25-pin DTE regarding the signal pinout, but does not use a connected intended for DTEs but a connector intended for DCEs like modems.
The PC USB to RS232 adapter cable is a standard 9-pin DTE that can directly connect to a standard 9-pin DCE.
The gray adapter is a standard adaptert that allows you to connect a standard 9-pin DTE to a standard 25-pin DCE.
And that's where it goes wrong, because the Philips uses a DCE connector, you can plug these together and it won't work, because TXD will connect to TXD etc.
Either make a custom cable or adapter, or use a gender changer on the Philips to make it have the correct port type and then you can use a standard null-modem cable.

Usually the gender of the connector was a good indicator of what the pinout would be, but there were always exceptions.  I think the female connectors were just easier to come by for PCB mount.  I like your idea of using a simple gender changer to make it conform to the usual standards.  Those used to be cheap and plentiful, don't know if they still are.

Back in the 80's I used a book called The RS-232 solution and a 25-way breakout box. This was a good summary of the techniques of the day when trying to connect to a 25-bit serial port. Some pins were commonly associated with particular functions, but there was no standard. The book tells you to trust nothing and try everything from scratch. Sometimes a line was used to supply power, or it had to be asserted for communication to work. I found at least one device which could not connect without adding a battery to the cable, which was something that even this book did not cover. But once you have read the book and learned to trust nothing, you can do things like this.

There is no need to try everything from scratch or other weird things to solve this. The problem is clear - the old computer uses DTE-side pinout on a DCE-side connector, so standard adapters cannot work until an adapter is used to standardize the pinout or connector.

@Justme, the problem, in this case, may be clear to you. But, there's more wrong ways to put an RS-232 port on a device than I can count, and I'm pretty sure that in my 45-year career, I've seen all of them (and more!) It all started the first time somebody tried to connect something that was not a modem to something else that also was not a modem. Ever since then, a wise person approaches the problem with a drawer full of RS-232 "testers" and break-out boxes, and gender menders, and null modems, and enough shells and pins from which a fully custom cable can be built if necessary.

It's nice to see you can still get those breakout boxes.  I still have an old one (belonging to my father) that comes out every few years.  The LEDs are helpful, but rather dim on USB-serial ports at 5V

Also I've had devices that didn't work with cheap USB-serial cables but did with Keyspan adaptors

Oops... in the old days, we used to heavily use the RS232 connections. An I can remember that we had a small broken junction box (jonction éclatée in French). Each pin was attached to a LED which made easier to see where were the signals, and we also had small cables to link any pin from connection 1 to any pin (or even pins) on connection 2.
I do not know if those tools still exist, but they was a must have to debug the hardware connection problems on RS232 because 2 cabling existed: either as a Data Terminal (console) or Data Set (modem). And you cannot always correctly guess what cabling was used on printers or computers...
Maybe you can try to use your oscilloscope to guess how your USB/RS232 is actually cabled to see if you need a NULL modem cable (switching send and receive and handling various other signals linke Clear To Send and Request To Send, Data Terminal Ready and Data Set Ready, Carrier Detect, ...)

These rs232 breakout boxes are still available on Amazon, eBay and other retail outlets...

There is no need to use such debugging device or guess. The Philips P2000C manual is available for pinout, as well as photos for determining connector type. The problem is not in the USB/RS232 adapter.

@Justme: The breakout box used to be a great tool to change the gender (DTE vs DCE) of a connector with full control of what was happening. You are right on one point: when the connection has been understood and works, it becomes useless... at least if you are able to build the custom adapter.

@Justme, Sometimes the official documentation is not enough. Sometimes the docs can be incomplete or ambiguous. Let's suppose that the doc labels a pin "TX." Does that mean it's the pin that the device will drive to transmit information to the host? Or, does it mean that it's the pin that the host will drive to transmit information to the device? I've seen both in the docs for real, commercial devices. "RTFM" is good advice in general, but "RTFM and keep your eyes open" is better advice when dealing with async serial ports.

Let me first emphasize that the answer of supercat was spot-on. I needed to use a so-called null-modem cable that swaps pins 2 and 3. Let me also thank the valuable contributions of other members of this community in sharing a lot of additional information on the RS232 protocol and its hardware. As promised in my comment, I would like to share the details of my setup, i.e. how I wired everything together and how I managed to transfer data between the P2000C and my modern computer.
The hardware
Besides the DB25 to DB9 adapter, I used a null-modem adapter (the orange block in the image below). Because the null-modem adapter has female-female connectors, I also needed to use an additional gender changer adapter (the yellow block) to connect it to the DB25 to DB9 adapter. After the null-modem cable, there is the serial-to-USB cable as mentioned earlier. This cable uses a CH340g chip. This is of course not the most elegant set-up, but it works.

Serial communication parameters
As already elucidated from the readout on the oscilloscope in my question, the serial communication parameters correspond to a baud rate of 1200, a bytelength of 8, a single stop byte and no parity checking. Per the advice of supercat, I ignored any form of handshaking. Note that these settings are the default settings. One can change these settings on the P2000C by making an interrupt call to 14,0. More information on the serial communication interrupt routines can be found in the manual starting on page 502. The maximum baud rate is apparently 9600.
The software
To test the program, I wrote the following 8088-assembly code in MS-DOS debug on the P2000C as shown by the image below. Note that the P2000C is not a native MS-DOS machine (as also pointed out by Raffzahn in their comment), but I happen to own one with a 8088 CoPower board and I booted my P2000C in the MS-DOS environment.

On my modern computer, I wrote a small Python script using the PySerial library as shown by the listing below.
import serial

def main():
    ser = serial.Serial('COM5', 1200, timeout=10)
    if not ser.isOpen():
        ser.open()
    ser.write('Hello World!'.encode('ascii'))
    ser.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Executing the Python script transfers the string 'Hello World!' over to the P2000C and displays it on the screen (as can be seen in the image above). The 8088-assembly program is written such that it keeps on consuming characters from the serial connection until a timeout is received, which happens (as mentioned in the documentation) after 20 seconds of not receiving any new characters.
Reversing the direction
Clearly, receiving data from a modern computer on the P2000C is working. I also wanted to test the other direction, i.e. sending data from the P2000C to a modern computer. For that, I used the 8088-assembly code as shown in the image below. In this short program, I basically set a pointer to address 0x110 and consume 0x0C (12) characters and transfer each character over the serial port to the modern PC. Although not explicitly shown here, I was able to receive the "Hello World!" string on my modern computer.


loop decrements CX, so better use 'MOV CX,0C' or your loop may run 256 times CH more times than you expected ;-)

@Tommylee2k That is a very good point! Thanks for pointing this out. It is the case that DEBUG.COM resets all registers such that CH is 0, but nevertheless better to use MOV CX,0C.

It looks like you have resolved the issue re DTC/DCE pinning, but a common problem with BIOS or DOS communication calls was the expectation that the incoming handshake lines would be functional and active. Some systems (e.g. original IBM PC) wouldn't transmit if CTS was de-asserted, and wouldn't receive if DSR was de-asserted.
Some USB-serial adapters seem made for Arduinos and only have TXD,RXD,RTS,CTS which won't work in the above scenario if the handshake pins aren't looped back as expected.
Another diversion, less likely with a proper PC, is peripheral devices which cheaped out on RS-232 interface chips and only used a transistor pull-up to local VCC or 12V with a resistor to GND (or even worse, just drove a 5V digital signal out). We found this approach on a multi-kilobuck mains interference analyser (OK, maybe it was an opto-isolator output but still...) which worked on cheap clone PCs but wouldn't work on the Dean's multi-kilobuck Toshiba colour LCD luggable PC. It seems Toshiba connected the bias pin on their line receivers and required a negative-going input signal to function.
I think the pin naming back in the 80s was supposed to be from the DTE end - so pin 2 on a D25 was TXD on both the PC and MODEM, but was an output on one and an input on the other.

Well, that's cleary not an Arduino toy but a real USB-RS232-UART adapter. It looks so familiar that I likely have used same adapter too, it likely has a Prolific PL2302 USB UART chip (not best but adequate) and some Maxim or similar RS-232 transceiver with charge pump for boosting the USB 5V to maybe +/- 7V.

Aren't the Prolific adapters the ones that FTDI broke with their driver hacking?

@davolfman If you are referring to the "FTDIgate scandal", I would not know. Why would Prolific make chips that read Prolific on them but the chips saying to PC they are FTDI VID:PID? They were fake FTDI chips with fake FTDI labels that stopped working when FTDI made some driver/firmware update that did not work on unofficial/clone chips. It's really not FTDIs fault they tried to make updates that bricked cloned chips, I bet they did not do it on purpose.

@justme I read it as they used FTDI's driver so they wouldn't have pay to develop and pay to sign their own.  The short is: some serial adapters just don't work if they're old enough.

@davolfman I think you are combining two issues. FTDIGate caused clone devices announcing they were FTDI to brick themselves. AIUI Prolific removed the PIDs of their earlier chips from the signed driver INF files, rendering them unusable, because there were so many badly implemented clones it was giving Prolific a bad reputation.
